# Do we say "as it" or "as if" to say "as it is right now"?

Tags: expression-choice

In casual speech, take this conversation, for example:

> *Person A*: Here's the message: "Hi, my name is [...] Cheers"
>
> *Person A*: Do I send it **as it is right now**?
>
> *Person B*: Yeah, no problem send it like that.

I often shorten the "as it is right now" part but I'm not sure if the correct way to say is "as it" or "as if".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *as **if*** would be wrong. You mean *as is*:

> Do I send it as is?